# Simplest way to script slowly sending data through a socket connection

Tags: linux, sockets, scripting, tcp

I need to periodically connect to a server from a Linux client and send some commands, so I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
telnet theserver.somewhere.com 9999 <<EOF
command 1
command 2
command 3
EOF
```

The problem is that I need to wait between commands. This script sends the commands and disconnects too quickly, which the server detects, and drops the commands. It works if I open the connection from the command line and then paste the commands one at a time, and it works from non-local clients, but from local clients the script fails. It would be enough to just pause for a second or so between each command.

I can write a C or Java program that does this, but what is the simplest way? The usual scripting languages (Perl and Python) are available, if you need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell commands to echo a line at a time from a file to telnet:

```
cat commands.txt | 
    ( while read line; do echo $line; sleep 1; done ) |
    telnet theserver.somewhere.com 9999
```

Comment: Thanks! A very short script, and uses nothing but the shell and standard commands. If I hadn't already used RoeeK's Python script, I would have used this one.

Answer (score 2):

first, if the server code is in your control then i suggest you fix this problem in the server, cause there is no actual reason why 'closing the connection too fast' would have a problem.

then, i would write a little and simple python script:

```
#!/bin/python

import socket,time

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
s.connect(("theserver.somewhere.com",9999))
s.sendall("1")
time.sleep(1)
s.sendall("2")
time.sleep(1)
s.close()
```

Comment: This works, is reasonably simple, and I'm using it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
set s [socket $HOST $PORT]
fconfigure $s -buffering line
puts $s $command1
sleep $no_of_sec
puts $s $command2
```

My TCL is a bit rusty but I think it's the easiest way to go. You can also use some Tk to do wonders. http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/tutorial/tcltutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Sleep command? I am not sure if this will work as it might try to issue that command on the other server but it is worth a shot just issue something like sleep 2 to pause for acouple seconds.

Comment: I can't manage to escape into command mode in telnet. It works when typing things by hand, but for some reason not in the script. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of problem that Expect was designed to solve.

http://expect.sourceforge.net/